# Migation from weblogic to jboss: configuration changes

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I am new to Jboss server. I am migrating the J2ee application from  Weblogic 10.2 to JBoss EAP 6.1.0. While migrating I am getting the below error message. Kindly assist if anyone knows the solution.

i tried to change the configuration files but was unable to find move all the tags to Jboss.

following are my configation files:

weblogic.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wls="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90 http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
  <wls:context-root>Stateless</wls:context-root>
  <wls:library-ref>
    <wls:library-name>beehive-controls-1.0.1-10.0-war</wls:library-name>
    <wls:specification-version>1.0</wls:specification-version>
    <wls:exact-match>true</wls:exact-match>
  </wls:library-ref>
  <wls:library-ref>
    <wls:library-name>jstl</wls:library-name>
    <wls:specification-version>1.1</wls:specification-version>
    <wls:exact-match>true</wls:exact-match>
  </wls:library-ref>
  <wls:library-ref>
    <wls:library-name>struts-1.2</wls:library-name>
    <wls:specification-version>1.2</wls:specification-version>
    <wls:exact-match>true</wls:exact-match>
  </wls:library-ref>
  <wls:library-ref>
    <wls:library-name>weblogic-controls-10.0-war</wls:library-name>
    <wls:specification-version>10.0</wls:specification-version>
    <wls:exact-match>true</wls:exact-match>
  </wls:library-ref>
  <wls:library-ref>
    <wls:library-name>wls-commonslogging-bridge-war</wls:library-name>
    <wls:specification-version>1.0</wls:specification-version>
    <wls:exact-match>true</wls:exact-match>
  </wls:library-ref>
  <wls:library-ref>
    <wls:library-name>beehive-netui-1.0.1-10.0</wls:library-name>
    <wls:specification-version>1.0</wls:specification-version>
    <wls:exact-match>true</wls:exact-match>
  </wls:library-ref>
  <wls:library-ref>
    <wls:library-name>beehive-netui-resources-1.0.1-10.0</wls:library-name>
    <wls:specification-version>1.0</wls:specification-version>
    <wls:exact-match>true</wls:exact-match>
  </wls:library-ref>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Jboss-web.xml:

```
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
xmlns:wls="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
wls:schemaLocation="     
http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee      
http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd"> 
  <context-root>Stateless</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

how to specify the `<library-ref>` in jboss ??

Answer (score 0):

There is no error message below, please edit your post.
The simpler method should be to package your jars in your war project.

Comment: If the <library-ref> is used in jboss-web.xml, it shows error. Is there any corresponding tag in jboss for the same??

Comment: Also the application contains both weblogic-ejb-jar.xml and ejb-jar.xml. Only the weblogic-ejb-jar.xml needs to be changed to jboss-ejb3.xml or both the configuration files?